# Is it possible to have a function in a controller act as if the controller has the [ApiController] attribute but it has not?

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a .net core MVC project that uses AJAX to retrieve data when loading grids.

Today, both the function returning the view and the function returning the data for the grid, is in the same controller. This is not optimal for many reasons. I.e. I would like a Json ProblemResult to be returned if a exception occurs when calling function using AJAX, but when returning a View, I would like the Developer Exception page to be shown if an error occurs.

I could split the functions into different Controllers and annotate one of them with the ApiController attribute, but since the project has several hundreds of controllers it would be a significant task to do so.

What I would like is this:
If context type is application/json: Do model validation and return a “ProblemResult” if a exception occurs, otherwise use the Developers Exception Page to show the error.

Can this be done in a easy way, or do I need to build a middleware and handle it all by myself?

Answer (score 1):

The easy way, meaning, doing this from a function that returns either a view or a type of JSON result would look something like this:

```cs
public IActionResult AjaxOrView(CheckModel model)
{    
    var isAjax = Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest";
    var modelStateValid = ModelState.IsValid;

    if (isAjax)
    {
        if (!modelStateValid)
        {
           return JsonProblemResult(); 
        }

        return Json();
    }

    if (!modelStateValid)
    {
       // this will throw and the exception page will be shown
       throw new Exception();
    }

    return View();
}
```